# How are the allowed values of _POSIX_THREADS in Open Group Base Spec 6 to be interpreted?

Tags: boost, pthreads, posix, standards

This [version of the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/) states that the [allowed values for the symbol _POSIX_THREADS](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/unistd.h.html) are -1, 0, or 200112L, but does not state what each value represents.

Comments [in boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/boost/config/posix_features.hpp) suggest that values greater than zero indicate posix thread support, but the nearby preprocessor check appears to interpret zero as meaning 'threads enabled' as well.

How are the three permitted values to be interpreted? In particular, does -1 mean 'no threads'? Does zero mean threads or no threads? I'm guessing that 200112L means threads, but I'd be interested in more information on that as well.

Basically I just want to verify that the boost preprocessor check is the correct way to test for the presence of posix threads, despite what looks to be a slightly misleading comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the POSIX spec page you reference:

> If a symbolic constant is defined with the value -1, the option is not supported. Headers, data types, and function interfaces required only for the option need not be supplied. An application that attempts to use anything associated only with the option is considered to be requiring an extension.
>
> If a symbolic constant is defined with a value greater than zero, the option shall always be supported when the application is executed. All headers, data types, and functions shall be present and shall operate as specified.
>
> If a symbolic constant is defined with the value zero, all headers, data types, and functions shall be present. The application can check at runtime to see whether the option is supported by calling fpathconf(), pathconf(), or sysconf() with the indicated name parameter.

Comment: Wow not sure how I missed that part. I guess Ctrl-F for _POSIX_THREADS skipped me past the relevant part. Thanks for pointing that out.